# Is it a good idea to replace ListView with RecyclerView

Tags: android

In my app I am planning to replace `ListView` with `RecyclerView` because in my app i want my `ListView` width should be `WRAP_CONTENT`  but it is not working. It just fills my whole screen. Does `RecyclerView` can solve this issue? I heard its more flexible and advanced version of `ListView`.

Comment: what you want ? code pls

Comment: you may try to solve your problem in ListView.many methods are avilable to set height as per child content in ListView.

Comment: @Basi I have a listview in my project .I want my Listview width to be wrap content but when i try to use it does not work and simply covers the whole screen.I want my listview width to be short and covers the elements inside it.

Comment: post your `listview xml` and `item_list xml` file so people get idea what is wrong with you .......